# Between/within standard deviations

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, stata, multi-level

When working on a hierarchical/multilevel/panel dataset, it may be very useful to adopt a package which returns the within- and between-group standard deviations of the available variables.

This is something that with the following data in `Stata` can be easily done through the command

```
xtsum, i(momid)
```

I made a research, but I cannot find any `R` package which can do that..

**edit:**

Just to fix ideas, an example of hierarchical dataset could be this:

```
son_id       mom_id      hispanic     mom_smoke     son_birthweigth

  1            1            1            1              3950
  2            1            1            0              3890
  3            1            1            0              3990
  1            2            0            1              4200
  2            2            0            1              4120
  1            3            0            0              2975
  2            3            0            1              2980
```

The "multilevel" structure is given by the fact that each mother (higher level) has two or more sons (lower level). Hence, each mother defines a group of observations.

Accordingly, each dataset variable can vary either between and within mothers or only between mothers. `birtweigth` varies among mothers, but also within the same mother. Instead, `hispanic` is fixed for the same mother.

For example, the within-mother variance of `son_birthweigth` is:

```
# mom1 means
    bwt_mean1 <- (3950+3890+3990)/3
    bwt_mean2 <- (4200+4120)/2
    bwt_mean3 <- (2975+2980)/2

# Within-mother variance for birthweigth
    ((3950-bwt_mean1)^2 + (3890-bwt_mean1)^2 + (3990-bwt_mean1)^2 + 
    (4200-bwt_mean2)^2 + (4120-bwt_mean2)^2 + 
    (2975-bwt_mean3)^2 + (2980-bwt_mean3)^2)/(7-1)
```

While the between-mother variance is:

```
# overall mean of birthweigth:
# mean <- sum(data$son_birthweigth)/length(data$son_birthweigth)
    mean <- (3950+3890+3990+4200+4120+2975+2980)/7

# within variance:
    ((bwt_mean1-mean)^2 + (bwt_mean2-mean)^2 + (bwt_mean3-mean)^2)/(3-1)
```

Comment: do you mean raw moments or estimates from a hierarchical model?  If the latter, does `VarCorr` do what you want (from `nlme::lme` or `lme4::lmer`)?

Comment: I mean the sample moments of the empirical distributions of variables, where each variable's overall standard deviation can be split into the within- and between-cluster components.

Comment: @Stezzo yes you give the data. It would better to give also the expected result. It is not clear, do you want to compute the moments of `son_birthweigth` over other categorical variables?

Comment: @ agstudy I put a numerical example for making things clearer. Thanks for any additional help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your Stata command should reproduce, but to answer the second part of the question about
hierarchical structure: it is easy to do this with `list`.
For example, you define a structure like this:

```
tree = list(
      "var1" = list(
         "panel" = list(type ='p',mean = 1,sd=0)
         ,"cluster" = list(type = 'c',value = c(5,8,10)))
      ,"var2" = list(
          "panel" = list(type ='p',mean = 2,sd=0.5)
         ,"cluster" = list(type="c",value =c(1,2)))
)
```

To create this `lapply` it is convenient to work with `list`

```
tree <- lapply(list('var1','var2'),function(x){ 
  ll <- list(panel= list(type ='p',mean = rnorm(1),sd=0), ## I use symbol here not name
             cluster= list(type = 'c',value = rnorm(3)))  ## R prefer symbols
})
names(tree) <-c('var1','var2')
```

You can view the structure with `str`

```
str(tree)
List of 2
 $ var1:List of 2
  ..$ panel  :List of 3
  .. ..$ type: chr "p"
  .. ..$ mean: num 0.284
  .. ..$ sd  : num 0
  ..$ cluster:List of 2
  .. ..$ type : chr "c"
  .. ..$ value: num [1:3] 0.0722 -0.9413 0.6649
 $ var2:List of 2
  ..$ panel  :List of 3
  .. ..$ type: chr "p"
  .. ..$ mean: num -0.144
  .. ..$ sd  : num 0
  ..$ cluster:List of 2
  .. ..$ type : chr "c"
  .. ..$ value: num [1:3] -0.595 -1.795 -0.439
```

### Edit after OP clarification

I think that package `reshape2` is what you want. I will demonstrate here.

To do the multilevel analysis we need to reshape the data.

First, divide the variables into two groups: identifier and measured variables.

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat,id.vars=c('son_id','mom_id')) ## other columns are measured 

str(dat.m)
'data.frame':   21 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ son_id  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 ...
 $ mom_id  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "hispanic","mom_smoke",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ value   : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ..
```

Once you have data in "moten" form,  you can "cast" to rearrange it in the shape that you want:

```
# mom1 means for all variable
 acast(dat.m,variable~mom_id,mean)
                           1    2      3
hispanic           1.0000000    0    0.0
mom_smoke          0.3333333    1    0.5
son_birthweigth 3943.3333333 4160 2977.5
# Within-mother variance for birthweigth

acast(dat.m,variable~mom_id,function(x) sum((x-mean(x))^2))
                           1    2    3
hispanic           0.0000000    0  0.0
mom_smoke          0.6666667    0  0.5
son_birthweigth 5066.6666667 3200 12.5

## overall mean of each variable
acast(dat.m,variable~.,mean)
[,1]
hispanic           0.4285714
mom_smoke          0.5714286
son_birthweigth 3729.2857143
```

Comment: just glancing quickly over this -- are you sure you want `sum((x-mean(x))^2)` rather than `var(x)`?

Comment: You are right about the variance, the overall procedure seems ok though

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is four years old, but recently I wanted to do the same in R and came up with the following function. It depends on `dplyr` and `tibble`. Where: df is the dataframe, columns is a numerical vector to subset the dataframe and individuals is the column with the individuals.

```
xtsumR<-function(df,columns,individuals){
  df<-dplyr::arrange_(df,individuals)
  panel<-tibble::tibble()
  for (i in columns){
    v<-df %>% dplyr::group_by_() %>%
      dplyr::summarize_(
        mean=mean(df[[i]]),
        sd=sd(df[[i]]),
        min=min(df[[i]]),
        max=max(df[[i]])
      )
    v<-tibble::add_column(v,variacao="overal",.before=-1)
    v2<-aggregate(df[[i]],list(df[[individuals]]),"mean")[[2]]
    sdB<-sd(v2)
    varW<-df[[i]]-rep(v2,each=12) #
    varW<-varW+mean(df[[i]])
    sdW<-sd(varW)
    minB<-min(v2)
    maxB<-max(v2)
    minW<-min(varW)
    maxW<-max(varW)
    v<-rbind(v,c("between",NA,sdB,minB,maxB),c("within",NA,sdW,minW,maxW))
    panel<-rbind(panel,v)
  }
  var<-rep(names(df)[columns])
  n1<-rep(NA,length(columns))
  n2<-rep(NA,length(columns))
  var<-c(rbind(var,n1,n1))
  panel$var<-var
  panel<-panel[c(6,1:5)]
  names(panel)<-c("variable","variation","mean","standard.deviation","min","max")
  panel[3:6]<-as.numeric(unlist(panel[3:6]))
  panel[3:6]<-round(unlist(panel[3:6]),2)
  return(panel)
}
```